# Unclear about dynamic binding

Tags: java

I am not understanding the concept of dynamic binding and overriding properly:

Here is some code:

```
class Cake {
    public void taste (Cake c) {
        System.out.println("In taste of Cake class");
    }
}

class ChocolateCake extends Cake {
    public void taste(Cake c) {
        System.out.println("In taste (Cake version) of ChocolateCake class");
    }
    public void taste(ChocolateCake cc) {
        System.out.println("In taste (ChocolateCake version) of ChocolateCake class");
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ChocolateCake cc = new ChocolateCake();
    Cake c = new ChocolateCake();
    Cake c1 = new Cake();
    Cake c2 = new ChocolateCake();

    c1.taste(cc);
    c1.taste(c);

    c2.taste(cc);
    c2.taste(c);
}
```

I expected:

```
In taste of Cake class
In taste of Cake class
In taste (ChocolateCake version) of ChocolateCake class" <----
In taste (Cake version) of ChocolateCake class
```

Actual:

```
In taste of Cake class
In taste of Cake class
In taste (Cake version) of ChocolateCake class <----
In taste (Cake version) of ChocolateCake class
```

If the object is of type ChocolateCake and I call cc which is also ChocolateCake, how come the compiler shows it's getting Cake as a parameter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because Java uses both static and dynamic binding to choose a method to call in this case.

The line in question is this, right?

```
c2.taste(cc);
```

The compiler first chooses which method to call (static binding). Since `c2` is of compile time type `Cake`, the compiler only sees the `taste(Cake)` method. So it says "call `taste(Cake)`".

Now at runtime, the runtime needs to choose which implementation of `taste(Cake)` to call, depending on the runtime type of `c2`. This is dynamic binding. Does it choose the one in `Cake`? Or the one in `ChocolateCake`? Since `c2` is of runtime type `ChocolateCake`, it calls the implementation of `taste(Cake)` in `ChocolateCake`.

As you can see, the method that you thought would be called - `taste(ChocolateCake)` - is not even mentioned! This is because that is a different overload of the `taste` method, and because it is in the `ChocolateCake` class, which the compiler can't see. Why can't the compiler see? Because `c2` is of compile time type `Cake`.

In short, the compiler decides which overload, the runtime decides which implementation.

Responding to your statement:

> if the object is of type ChocolateCake ...

Only *you* know the object is of type `ChocolateCake`. The compiler does not. It only knows `c2` is of type `Cake` because that's what its declaration says.

Answer (score 8):

Since the reference type of the `c2` variable is `Cake` the `taste` method having the `Cake` type parameter will be called.

This is because the `Cake` type does not have the `taste` method which takes a `ChocolateCake` instance, so you can't invoke that method from a `Cake` type reference variable.

Now secondly, in Java due to the mechanism of runtime polymorphism the overridden `taste` method of the `ChocolateCake` is being called instead of the version declared in the parent `Cake` class. This is due to fact at runtime the object which the `Cake` reference is pointing to, will be examined and the `taste` version of that particular instance will be invoked.

So due to the combination of these two effects you see that output.

If you change the reference type of `c2` to `ChocolateCake` you would see that the output is:

```
In taste (ChocolateCake version) of ChocolateCake class
```

when you invoke `c2.taste(cc);`, since now both the compiler and runtime agrees to call that `taste(ChocolateCake cc)` method in particular.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the decision which methodset to call in case of `c2.taste(cc)` is performed at compile-time based on the compile-time type of `c2`. The compile-time type of `c2` is `Cake`, which means that *any* method call on `c2` is searching just class `Cake` and its superclasses, and isn't searching any subclasses of `Cake` (namely `ChocolateCake`) even if all the subclasses are visible to the compiler.

Languages performing fully dynamic method resolution at runtime based on the actual runtime types of the receiver&arguments, which would make `c2.taste(cc)` be resolved into `ChocolateCake.taste(ChocolateCake cc)`, are rare because it negatively affects runtime performance.